# JAXB default attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm using JAXB annotations to generate xsd schema from my classes.

Annotation @XmlElement with parameter defaultValue sets default value for element.
Is it possible to set default value for @XmlAttribute?

P.S. I checked that xsd syntax allow default values for attributes

Comment: What the... the annotation effectively doesn't have some defaultValue key. I'm actually quite surprised.

Comment: Default values for elements have been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371127) – maybe will help you for attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Might wanna check this: [Does JAXB support default schema values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423414/does-jaxb-support-default-schema-values?answertab=votes#tab-top)

To be honest, I don't have a clue why there isn't an attribute default option in standard JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate classes from an xsd where you define an attribute with a default value then jaxb will generate a if clause where it will check the null value and if so, will return the default value.

Answer (score 0):

For XML attributes default value goes inside getter method.

for Example,

customer.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="Customer">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="element" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" default="defaultElementName"></element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="attribute" type="string" default="defaultAttributeValue"></attribute>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

It will generate class like below.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "defaultElementName")
    protected String element;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute")
    protected String attribute;

    ......

    public String getAttribute() {
        //here the default value is set.
        if (attribute == null) {
            return "defaultAttributeValue";
        } else {
            return attribute;
        }
    }
```

Created Sample XML to read

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Customer><element/></Customer>
```

when we write logic to marshall in our main class.

```
File file = new File("...src/com/testdefault/xsd/CustomerRead.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(customer.getElement());
            System.out.println(customer.getAttribute());
```

It will print, in console.
defaultElementName
defaultAttributeValue

P.S -: to get default value of elements you need to have a blank copy of element into xml which is being marshalled.

Comment: OP asked about marshalling, not unmarshalling